# Angular 4 DI : wait for method completion

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient, angular-di

To avoid cyclic dependency i am using the `Injector` to inject the `AuthService` but when i run the application Angular execute the `intercept()` method before setting the `authService` property !!!

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{
  private authService;
   constructor(private injector: Injector) {
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.authService = injector.get(AuthService);
console.log('===========================================',this.authService);
        });
      }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
          }
        });

        return next.handle(request);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: do you need the setTimeout ? That's probably what's causing the timing issue.

Comment: Yes, I am using setTimeout just to wait until the authService property is set, I removed it and the error still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` shouldn't be used to avoid cyclic dependencies because it results in race conditions like this one.

The proper recipe to avoid cyclic dependencies is to retrieve them in-place. In case of interceptor class it is `intercept` method:

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    ...
  }
}
```

If there is a chance that interceptor is used in requests that are performed by a service that causes cyclic dependency (`AuthService`), additional safeguards should be added to the interceptor to avoid recursion.